# How do I get div to occupy entire height of parent div?

Tags: css

I am using a bootstrap based layout and there is div called "content" under that div I have placed all the component that is basically a large table, the divs as shown below. Problem is unless I specify some height explicitly to be div called scheduler_here (show below) it appears very tiny. I have included below what the div content css setup is below. I have tried specifying height as 100% and that doesn't work. I am not css expert and just learning. Any ideas how I should modify the parent "content" div so the scheduler will occupies remain height of the window, or show it with scrollbar?

```
<div id="content" class=" span10">
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container span10" style="height:2000px;width:95%">
     <div class="dhx_cal_navline" class="span10">
     <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>



#content {
       box-shadow: -3px -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.95);
       background: url("/static/img/bg.jpg") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
       filter: none;
       padding: 25px 0px 25px 40px;
       margin: -25px -4px;
       position: relative;
       z-index: 1;
       min-height: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: {
    height:inherit;
    }

or `{height:auto;}`

Comment: Actually if I set that the target div certainly doesn't occupy remaining entire height of the window. It behaves exactly same as if height were not specified.

Comment: to set height you need to use pixels. and as you <div>'s are empty so setting height to auto will always be 0px until the inner div's are empty.

Answer (score 2):

In order for the height (or min-height) to compute to a non-zero value when using a % value, the parent container need to have an explicit height value or a computed value.

In your case, you may need to set the height to the `html` and `body` tag to 100%, so I suggest you try:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

that way, your `#container` will inherit the viewport height and have well defined computed height value.

**Footnote**

You need to make sure that the height is set on all the block level ancestor elements that are between the body and the #container div. Either you inherit the height, set it to an explicit value (400px for example) or a relative value (ex: 100%).

Comment: When I view html and body rule in firefox debugger I see this so height and min-height is already set to 100%  html, body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
   }

Comment: Please see footnote regarding your comment.

Comment: FWIW I fixed my issue by registering onresize event and resizing the div in question.            $(document).ready(function(){
                resizeDiv();
        });

        window.onresize = function(event) {
                resizeDiv();
        }
        
        function resizeDiv() {
                console.log("RESIZE ME....");
                vpw = $(window).width(); 
                vph = $(window).height(); 
                $('#scheduler_here').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
        }

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I solved this issue by registering an onResize event handler.
Credit to: http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20271/setting-a-div-height-to-the-window-viewport-size/p1

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            resizeDiv();
    });

    window.onresize = function(event) {
            resizeDiv();
    }

    function resizeDiv() {
            vpw = $(window).width(); 
            vph = $(window).height(); 
            $('#scheduler_here').css({'height': vph + 'px'});
    }
```